# Swift: sort array by multiple criteria (weights)

Tags: xcode, swift, sorting, swift2

I've already read similar questions/answer, but none of it resolve my problem.

I've an object like this

```
class Chat {
    unreadMessages: Int = 0
    messages: Int = 0
}
```

Then I have an array of Chat objects, and I need to order it by multiple criteria, first by chat with grater unread messages and then chat with grater total messages.

**Es.**

```
  Obj  TotMes Unread  
  Chat A 10 3   
  Chat B  1 0     
  Chat C  4 0   
  Chat D  9 9
```

Desidered output:

```
Chat D  9 9   
Chat A 10 3   
Chat C  4 0  
Chat B  1 0
```

I try with this sort alhoritm, but don't seems work:

```
let sorted = chats.sort({ (c1, c2) -> Bool in   
   if c1.unreadMessages > c2.unreadMessages {
      return true
   }
   if c1.messages > c2.messages {
      return true
   }        
   return false
})
```

Can someone explain me what is wrong with this?

Comment: You could sort array by using predicate rules

Comment: Think about it: What should happen if `c1.unreadMessages < c2.unreadMessages` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't got condition for `c1.unreadMessages < c2.unreadMessages` that should cover all requirements:

```
let sorted = chats.sort({ (c1, c2) -> Bool in   
   if c1.unreadMessages > c2.unreadMessages {
      return true
   } else if c1.unreadMessages < c2.unreadMessages {
      return false
   } else if c1.messages > c2.messages {
      return true
   }        
   return false
})
```

Comment: Damn! Sure I forget one condition.. my fault! Thanks man!